# doctrine:database:create return ConnectionException and MysqliException

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine, connectionexception

command  php app/console doctrine:database:create

return errors:

> [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException]
>   An exception occured in driver: No such file or directory
>
> [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\Mysqli\MysqliException]
>   No such file or directory
>
> doctrine:database:create [--connection[="..."]] [--if-not-exists]

app/config/parameters.yml

```
parameters:
    database_driver: mysqli
    database_host: localhost
    database_port: 9998
    database_name: testing
    database_user: root
    database_password: root
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
    mailer_user: null
    mailer_password: null
    locale: en
    secret: ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
```

but this parameters is correctly
ps: I am used mamp pro.